# How to output built-in widgets with number in range as class?

Tags: widgets, responsive, html

I'd like to make my theme mobile friendly by turning the widget-containers into touchable buttons, having their contents flying out when hovering. Therefor, I will have to absolutely position the content of each container a few pixels more than its previous one.

Well, I could achieve that by planning how to arrange the widgets before the site goes live and then rely on the class-names WP generates commonly, but since I wanna leave the order up to the customer, this is not a solution.

The trick would be to pass each widget a class name in regard to its position in range. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could register many widget-areas, and rely on each one having its own unique wrapper class, to identify them one by one. Not sure how many you need.

Comment: Hmm this Dosen't seem to be a clean solution since it won't prevent users from placing multiple widgets in each area... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, first question I finally found the answer to by myself :-)

I found it [here at the WordPress forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-first-and-last-css-classes-for-sidebar-widgets). This post offers a correct code-snippet to add an index number to each widget plus to pass a `widget-first`/`widget-last`-class to the first/last one. Works like a charme!